# Adicionar perfil ao WebDriver FireFox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox-extensão, geckodriver

Bom dia
Estou automatizando um site, e para executar algumas funcionalidades se faz necessário o uso de uma extensão no navegador.
Primeiramente estava tentando adicionar a extensão no web driver com o

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addPreference("extensions.webextensions.ExtensionStorageIDB.migrated.websigner@softplan.com.br", true);
```

Pesquisando um pouco mais, me pareceu ser melhor importar um perfil do firefox ao instanciar o webDriver, estou tentando da seguinte forma

```
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(
            new File("/home/henrique/.mozilla/firefox/r6eis7qo.automacao"));
    options.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/home/files/logsGeckodriver.txt");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

porém o o webDriver não é instanciado, e tão pouco aponta algum erro, 
ao adicionar `options.setCapability("marionette", false);` ele instancia o webDriver, porém sem o perfil desejado

o perfil "automacao" esta personalizado com a extensão e as seguintes preferences

```
    options.addPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.dir", paramDownload);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
    options.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "application/pdf," + "text/plain," + "application/octet-stream," + "application/x-pdf,"
                    + "application/vnd.pdf," + "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheethtml,"
                    + "text/csv," + "text/html," + "application/x-msexcel," + "application/excel,"
                    + "application/x-excel," + "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    options.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
```

ao inspecionar o código ele encontra o perfil

```
new FirefoxProfile(
                new File("/home/henrique/.mozilla/firefox/r6eis7qo.automacao"));
```

e no firefox ao alternar entre perfis e conferir as configurações estão corretas

fiz esta pergunta no [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629725/how-do-i-add-a-profile-to-firefox-webdriver?noredirect=1#comment103572895_58629725), ela acabou sendo marcada como duplicada, porem as respostas não estão funcionando comigo.
Estou usando Selenium 3.141.59, FireFox 70.0 e geckodriver v0.24.0

Comment: Se o perfil gerado pelo GeckoDriver ou ChromeDriver é outro então não tem sentido pegar o uuid existente, porque o perfil é diferente do que usa padrão no seu usuário do OS, teria que instalar o add-on no momento que inicia o Driver usando `options.add_extension()` ou então pode criar um perfil a parte e carregar como algo assim `FirefoxProfile('/caminho/pasta/.mozilla/firefox/pastadoperfil')` e terá acesso a um perfil já configurado que você poderá ajustar e deixa-lo todo como deseja.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, e como eu configura um perfil? já tinha procurado na web por isso, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Estou sem tempo agora e usar o campo de comentários é complicado, mas a noite voto para reabrir a sua pergunta e respondo no campo apropriado para respostas como fazer o passo a passo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma

```
  FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.addPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.dir", paramDownload);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
    options.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "application/pdf," + "text/plain," + "application/octet-stream," + "application/x-pdf,"
                    + "application/vnd.pdf," + "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheethtml,"
                    + "text/csv," + "text/html," + "application/x-msexcel," + "application/excel,"
                    + "application/x-excel," + "application/vnd.ms-excel");

    options.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
    if (headless) {
        options.addArguments("--headless");
    }
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.addExtension(new File("/home/henrique/Documentos/websigner@softplan.com.br.xpi"));
    options.setProfile(firefoxProfile);

    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/home/files/logsGeckodriver.txt");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

para conseguir o .xpi da extensão, eu instalei a extensão em um perfil, e depois peguei o .xpi dentro da pasta do perfil

eu tmb percebi que da maneira citada na pergunta, de certa forma estava funcionando, porem ele demora cerca de inacreditáveis 20m para instanciar,  o webDriver, ele demorava tanto para renderizar o navegador que achava que não estava funcionando e matava a aplicação.

da maneira citada na resposta, ele demora(cerca de 1m) para renderizar somente na primeira vez ao startar o servidor, depois funciona normalmente